# Best way to call API when viewController is dismissed/Popped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, coding-style, logic

I want to call API when viewController is dismissed. So I have tried to call API in **viewWillDisappear** method. Do we have any other option like can we call notification and invoke API call. I just want to know best practices to do this. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: "I want to update the server when viewController is dismissed."  What does that mean?  Update server's what with your iPhone?

Comment: means want do call web-service.

Comment: Try below one  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self performSelector:@selector(methodNameHere) withObject:self afterDelay:0.6];
    }];

Answer (score 1):

When you dismiss view controller you have call back method in that you can call the API. Something like this below code

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];
```

Call the above method from the parent controller from where you have presented another controller.